# find: missing argument to `-exec' when using subprocess

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, ffmpeg

```
"find / -name 'testmkv-27311.mkv' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i testmkv-27311.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:480 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k {}testmkv-27311.mp4' \;"
```

> is the command i am passing and it gives error with find... there are some answers already about it but they are not making it clear... please help me execute this command...

Comment: You need to escape {} as \{}, like with the semicolon \;

Comment: that didn't work ....i tried

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: actuallly i am creating a string of this command and executing it in python as subprocess.Popen((this command).split(" "))

Comment: Please post the actual code you're using.  Note though, splitting that string on white space will not produce the command you want because your `bash -c` command will not be a single argument, that's probably the root of your problems.  Either leave it as a string with `shell=True` or build it up as a list instead of a string, or try `shlex.split` instead of naive string `split`

Comment: Also, please don't add information in the comments, instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45051547/edit) your question with the updated information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Immediate Issue: Shell Quoting vs Python Quoting

In an unquoted context in shell, `\;` prevents `;` from being parsed as a command separator. When invoking a command with an argument list from Python without `shell=True`, however, there *is* no shell to interpret and remove that backslash, and that extra quoting makes behavior equivalent to passing `'\;'` in shell -- meaning the argument passed to `find` isn't the exact string `;` it's expecting, and that you get a syntax error.

**However, the original code is incorrect (in security-impacting ways!) on other counts as well; one of the below solutions should be used.**

---

#### Smallest Change: Using `find` Safely

Personally, if you're willing to be a little flexible on the output names (ie. `testmkv-27311.mkv.avi`), I would write this more like the following:

```
subprocess.call([
  'find', '/',
  '-name', 'testmkv-27311.mkv',
  '-exec',
      'ffmpeg',
          '-i', '{}',
          '-vcodec', 'copy',
          '-acodec', 'copy',
          '-codec:v', 'libx264',
          '-profile:v', 'high',
          '-preset', 'slow',
          '-b:v', '500k',
          '-maxrate', '500k',
          '-bufsize', '1000k',
          '-vf', 'scale=-1:480',
          '-threads', '0',
          '-codec:a', 'libfdk_aac',
          '-b:a', '128k',
          '{}.mp4',
      ';',
])
```

Notably:

- We are **not** invoking a shell, and thus avoiding shell-injection-style security vulnerabilities.
- Quoting is all done purely with Python syntax -- no nested shell quoting is used or required.
- POSIX does not require `find -exec` to support `{}` as a substring (rather than a complete argument). As such, this answer is (like the code in the question) not as portable as might be hoped.

---

#### Alternate Approach: Native Python File Searching

That said, there isn't really a compelling reason to use `find` at all, when the Python standard library can do searches for you, *and* will make it easy to update the names yourself:

```
def convert(filename_in, filename_out):
  subprocess.call([
    'ffmpeg',
      '-i', filename_in,
      '-vcodec', 'copy',
      '-acodec', 'copy',
      '-codec:v', 'libx264',
      '-profile:v', 'high',
      '-preset', 'slow',
      '-b:v', '500k',
      '-maxrate', '500k',
      '-bufsize', '1000k',
      '-vf', 'scale=-1:480',
      '-threads', '0',
      '-codec:a', 'libfdk_aac',
      '-b:a', '128k',
      filename_out,
  ])

target = 'testmkv-27311.mkv'
for root, dir, files in os.walk('/'):
  if target in files:
    filename_in = os.path.join(dir, target)
    filename_out = filename_in[:-3]+'.mp4'
    convert(filename_in, filename_out)
```

---

#### Alternate Safe Approach: Hardcoded Script Iterating Over Arguments

As yet another approach to doing this securely (**not** having `find` modify or generate code from names, which allows those names to be parsed as code by the shell), you could have your bash script iterate over its arguments:

```
bash_script=r'''
for filename; do
  ffmpeg -i "$filename" \
         -vcodec copy \
         -acodec copy \
         -codec:v libx264 \
         -profile:v high \
         -preset slow \
         -b:v 500k \
         -maxrate 500k \
         -bufsize 1000k \
         -vf scale=-1:480 \
         -threads 0 \
         -codec:a libfdk_aac \
         -b:a 128k \
         "${filename%.mkv}.mp4}"
done
'''

subprocess.call([
  'find', '/',
    '-name', 'testmkv-27311.mkv',
    '-exec', 'bash', '-c', bash_script, '_',
    '{}', '+'])
```

In this case, the `_` is the placeholder for `$0` in the script; subsequent arguments (the filenames found by `find`) are passed in `$1`, `$2`, etc; and `for filename; do` (which defaults to `for filename in "$@"; do`) will iterate over them.

Using `-exec ... {} +` passes as many as filenames as possible to each command, rather than invoking the command once per filename; this reduces the number of shells invoked, and thus enhances performance.