# Python subprocess.Popen giving error with unix 'find' command

Tags: python, subprocess, find, popen, shlex

I am trying to get the largest 20 files in a directory that are older than 60 days by passing the unix 'find' command to Python's subprocess.Popen. This is what I have tried:

```
# Get largest files older than 60 days
cmd_string = 'find {0} -type f -mtime +60 -size +300M -exec du -sh {{}} \; | sort -rh | head -n20'.format(rmnt)
print(cmd_string)
cmd_args = shlex.split(cmd_string, posix=False)
print(cmd_args[12])
find_out = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
```

where rmnt is a directory name (eg. '/mnt/active'). The print statements return the command correctly:

```
find /mnt/active -type f -mtime +60 -size +300M -exec du -sh {} \; | sort -rh | head -n20
\;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I thought that the problem was due to the special character "\" but it is being printed as expected.

**Update 1.**

I found this similar question: [find: missing argument to `-exec' when using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051547/find-missing-argument-to-exec-when-using-subprocess)

It deals with subprocess.call rather than subprocess.Popen but the answer that "there is no shell to interpret and remove that backslash" seems to apply here also. However, with the backslash removed I still get an error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: |
```

This error suggests that the backslash is not being passed to the find command

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has a similar issue, there are 2 problems in my code.

**1.**

By default, subprocess.Popen uses `shell=False` and therefore there is no shell to interpret and remove the backslash as explained here: [find: missing argument to `-exec' when using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051547/find-missing-argument-to-exec-when-using-subprocess)

**2.**

To use a pipe with the subprocess module, you have to pass `shell=True` which is a security hazard. Therefore, the commands should be separated into 2 or more commands as explained here: [How to use `subprocess` command with pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes)

The code that worked for me is:

```
# Get largest files older than 60 days
find_cmd = 'find {0} -type f -mtime +60 -size +300M -exec du -sh {{}} ;'.format(rmnt)
find_args = shlex.split(find_cmd)
sort_cmd = 'sort -rh'
sort_args = shlex.split(sort_cmd)

find_process = subprocess.Popen(find_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sort_process = subprocess.Popen(sort_args, stdin=find_process.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
find_process.stdout.close()
sort_out = sort_process.stdout
```